# Having trouble running code in Eclipse using JOGL

Tags: java, eclipse, jogl

I'm trying to run an application in eclipse which is setup as MVC app and it is the solution code posted by our professor for a homework. After I copy and pasted all of the classes and tried to run it, I got the following error:

### JOGL> Hello JOAL Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jogamp/openal/JoalVersion at jogamp.opengl.openal.av.ALDummyUsage.main(ALDummyUsage.java:14) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jogamp.openal.JoalVersion at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ... 1 more

I'm not entirely sure what the issue is and apparently no one else has been having the same issue.

My buildpath has a library I titled "JOGL" and I added the external jars gluegen-rt.jar and jogl-all.jar as was instructed by the professor.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code uses JOAL too, you need to put joal.jar into your classpath (Build path in Eclipse) and you need to put the JAR(s) containing its native libraries into the same directory as you did for JOGL and GlueGen. I assume you followed these instructions:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_a_JogAmp_project_in_your_favorite_IDE#Eclipse_IDE_project

Edit.: You don't run your own program for your homework, you try to run ALDummyUsage which is in JOGL itself. If you want to run your own program with your own main class, rather right-click on it and choose "Run As" -> "Java application" in Eclipse.